# How to use pandas aggregate Datetime object to int

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, aggregate

I have a DataFrame structure like that

```
         id   time                   number
0        1    1970-01-01 00:00:00    1
1        2    1970-01-02 00:00:00    2
2        1    1970-01-03 00:00:00    2
```

I want the groupby `id` and aggregate the time which have `pd.Datetime` dtype to be `int` representing the time delta and I have the code below:

```
def interval(a):
    return (np.max(a) - np.min(a)).days

_df = df.groupby(['id'], as_index=False).agg(
        {
            "number": numpy.sum,
            "time": interval,
        }
    )
```

The column time has origin dtype `pd.Datetime` however the aggregated data is int which results the data in `time` column of `_df` are converted from int to `pd.Datetime` like `1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000`

Could you tell me how to get the correct result which the `time` column of aggregated dataframe is `int`

Answer (score 3):

You can try convert `timedelta` to `days` by `np.timedelta64(1, 'D')` and then `float` to `integer` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
def interval(a):
    a = (np.max(a) - np.min(a)) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
    return a

_df = df.groupby(['id'], as_index=False).agg(
        {
            "number": np.sum,
            "time": interval,
        }
    )
_df['time']  = _df['time'].astype(int)  
print _df  

   id  number  time
0   1       3     2
1   2       2     0
```